Horror movie about demons
I feel like this is a fairly well known movie but I just can't tell or not. I only remember one scene and it's kind of specific enough to sound familiar if you've seen it but if you haven't then it'll be hard to find. I saw it years ago just this scene and then I left the room, It was in Spanish so I didn't understand the situation, but it could have been dubbed. I think it may have come out in the early or mid 200's but im not sure. So here it goes.
There were about five people (I remember there being an old lady too) in a room and they were trying to get rid of an evil spirit or demon and in order to do so they had to all carry a mirror or drawer with a mirror and throw it out the window.  And it was super important that they all kept their eyes closed or else the demon would eacape, and as they were carrying the mirror thing and one guy opened his eyes and the demon escaped.  And then chaos ensued.

Could it be Constantine with Keanu Reeves?
Below is the similar scene from the film :




Can you explain why you think this is the answer?

because it starts with this scene

@Monica I think i remember something like that but can you post some video or images as a proof or movie plot explaining the scene from some source. As one liners not reciprocated very well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZIGLJWzGHY

Yest this is same movie.

I'd say it would also be worth summering the content of the scene in text so people can find it (can't search just with the video clip).
